# Is there a way to read a parquet file with apache flink?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, parquet

I'm new on Apache Flink and I cannot find a way to read a parquet file from the file system.
I came from Spark where a simple "spark.read.parquet("...")" did the job.
Is it possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it depends on the way your are going to read the parquet.
If you are trying to simply read parquet files and want to leverage a DataStream connector, [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514057/process-continuously-parquet-files-as-datastreams-in-flinks-datastream-api) can be the entry point and a working example.

If you prefer the Table API, [Table & SQL Connectors - Parquet Format](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/formats/parquet.html) can be helpful to start from.