# How to print the total number of lines in files using flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading lines from parquet for that I am using source functions similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54551354/1928414) , however when I try counting number of lines being processed, nothing is printed although the job is completed :

```
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
lazy val stream: DataStream[Group] = env.addSource(new ParquetSourceFunction)
stream.map(_ => 1)                    
    .timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(180)) 
    .reduce( _ + _).print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the fact that You are using `ProcessingTime`, so basically whenever You are using the `EventTime` when the file is finished Flink is emitting a watemark with `Long.Max` value so that all windows are closed, but this does not happen when working  with `ProcessingTime`, so simply speaking Flink doesn't wait for Your window to close and that's why You are not getting any valuable results.

You may want to try to switch to `DataSet` API, which should be more appropriate for the task You want to achieve.

Alternatively, You may try to play with `EventTime` and assign static Watermark, since Flink at the end will still emit watermark with `Long.Max` value.